# DataGirdView не все ячейки отрисовываются

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Для того, чтобы таблицы большого объема не мерцали при скроллинге, в интернете есть решение включить у DataGridView двойную буферизацию. После ее включения мерцание прекращается. 
Появилась другая проблема-не все ячейки отображаются.

До включения DoubleBuffered
[image: До включения DoubleBuffered]

После включения DoubleBuffered
[image: После включения DoubleBuffered]

Не отображается та часть ячеек у которых добавлена возможность объединения по столбцам и строкам. Эта задача решается переопределением мотода Paint класса-наследника DataGridViewTextBoxCell.
К сожалению класс писал не сам и не могу разобраться что изменить в методе.
(классы брал [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour))
Сам метод:

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            if (m_OwnerCell != null && m_OwnerCell.DataGridView == null)
                m_OwnerCell = null; //owner cell was removed.

            if (DataGridView == null
                || (m_OwnerCell == null && m_ColumnSpan == 1 && m_RowSpan == 1))
            {
                base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle,
                        paintParts);
                return;
            }

            var ownerCell = this;
            var columnIndex = ColumnIndex;
            var columnSpan = m_ColumnSpan;
            var rowSpan = m_RowSpan;
            if (m_OwnerCell != null)
            {
                ownerCell = m_OwnerCell;
                columnIndex = m_OwnerCell.ColumnIndex;
                rowIndex = m_OwnerCell.RowIndex;
                columnSpan = m_OwnerCell.ColumnSpan;
                rowSpan = m_OwnerCell.RowSpan;
                value = m_OwnerCell.GetValue(rowIndex);
                errorText = m_OwnerCell.GetErrorText(rowIndex);
                cellState = m_OwnerCell.State;
                cellStyle = m_OwnerCell.GetInheritedStyle(null, rowIndex, true);
                formattedValue = m_OwnerCell.GetFormattedValue(value,
                    rowIndex, ref cellStyle, null, null, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Display);
            }
            if (CellsRegionContainsSelectedCell(columnIndex, rowIndex, columnSpan, rowSpan))
                cellState |= DataGridViewElementStates.Selected;

            var cellBounds2 = DataGridViewCellExHelper.GetSpannedCellBoundsFromChildCellBounds(
                this,
                cellBounds,
                DataGridViewHelper.SingleVerticalBorderAdded(DataGridView),
                DataGridViewHelper.SingleHorizontalBorderAdded(DataGridView));
            clipBounds = DataGridViewCellExHelper.GetSpannedCellClipBounds(ownerCell, cellBounds2,
                DataGridViewHelper.SingleVerticalBorderAdded(DataGridView),
                DataGridViewHelper.SingleHorizontalBorderAdded(DataGridView));
            using (var g = DataGridView.CreateGraphics())
            {
                g.SetClip(clipBounds);
                //Paint the content.
                advancedBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellExHelper.AdjustCellBorderStyle(ownerCell);
                ownerCell.NativePaint(g, clipBounds, cellBounds2, rowIndex, cellState,
                    value, formattedValue, errorText,
                    cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle,
                    paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
                //Paint the borders.
                if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None)
                {
                    var leftTopCell = ownerCell;
                    var advancedBorderStyle2 = new DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle
                                                   {
                        Left = advancedBorderStyle.Left,
                        Top = advancedBorderStyle.Top,
                        Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                        Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
                    };
                    leftTopCell.PaintBorder(g, clipBounds, cellBounds2, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle2);

                    var rightBottomCell = DataGridView[columnIndex + columnSpan - 1, rowIndex + rowSpan - 1] as DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx 
                                          ?? this;
                    var advancedBorderStyle3 = new DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle
                    {
                        Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                        Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                        Right = advancedBorderStyle.Right,
                        Bottom = advancedBorderStyle.Bottom
                    };
                    rightBottomCell.PaintBorder(g, clipBounds, cellBounds2, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle3);
                }
            }
        }
```

Получается, что у тех ячеек, у которых m_ColumnSpan и m_RowSpan установлены в 1, отрисовываются правильно, так как у них просто вызывается родительский метод Paint, а если эти значения больше 1, то метод работает неверно.

Comment: Попробуйте не создавать g, а использовать graphics, который передается в метод Paint

Comment: @petya не помогло. Стало еще хуже, почти все ячейки черные.

Answer (score 0):

Решаю ту же проблему с не отрисовкой объединенных ячеек в DataGridView. Вопрос вижу задан давненько. Ответ здесь https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4477514/double-buffer-for-the-datagridview в разработке автора. У меня получилось, правда с некоторой корректировкой. Если для Вас это ещё актуально расскажу подробнее, у меня проект на гитхабе, но мне нужно время дооформить.

```
        protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds, System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            if (m_OwnerCell != null && m_OwnerCell.DataGridView == null)
            {
                m_OwnerCell = null; //owner cell was removed.
            }

            if (DataGridView == null || (m_OwnerCell == null && m_ColumnSpan == 1 && m_RowSpan == 1))
            {
                base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
                return;
            }

            var ownerCell = this;
            var columnIndex = ColumnIndex;
            var columnSpan = m_ColumnSpan;
            var rowSpan = m_RowSpan;
            if (m_OwnerCell != null)
            {
                ownerCell = m_OwnerCell;
                columnIndex = m_OwnerCell.ColumnIndex;
                rowIndex = m_OwnerCell.RowIndex;
                columnSpan = m_OwnerCell.ColumnSpan;
                rowSpan = m_OwnerCell.RowSpan;
                value = m_OwnerCell.GetValue(rowIndex);
                errorText = m_OwnerCell.GetErrorText(rowIndex);
                cellState = m_OwnerCell.State;
                cellStyle = m_OwnerCell.GetInheritedStyle(null, rowIndex, true);
                formattedValue = m_OwnerCell.GetFormattedValue(value, rowIndex, ref cellStyle, null, null, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Display);
            }

            if (CellsRegionContainsSelectedCell(columnIndex, rowIndex, columnSpan, rowSpan))
            {
                cellState |= DataGridViewElementStates.Selected;
            }

            // Store the old Clip Bound
            RectangleF oldBounds = graphics.ClipBounds;
            var cellBounds2 = DataGridViewCellExHelper.GetSpannedCellBoundsFromChildCellBounds(this, cellBounds, DataGridView.SingleVerticalBorderAdded(), DataGridView.SingleHorizontalBorderAdded());
            clipBounds = DataGridViewCellExHelper.GetSpannedCellClipBounds(ownerCell, cellBounds2, DataGridView.SingleVerticalBorderAdded(), DataGridView.SingleHorizontalBorderAdded());

            advancedBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellExHelper.AdjustCellBorderStyle(ownerCell);

            using (var g = this.DataGridView.CreateGraphics())
            {
                // Set the new Clip Bounds to the bounds which are calulcated for the row to span.
                g.SetClip(clipBounds);

                //Paint the content.
                ownerCell.NativePaint(g, clipBounds, cellBounds2, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);

                //Paint the borders.
                if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None)
                {
                    var leftTopCell = ownerCell;
                    var advancedBorderStyle2 = new DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle
                    {
                        Left = advancedBorderStyle.Left,
                        Top = advancedBorderStyle.Top,
                        Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                        Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
                    };
                    leftTopCell.PaintBorder(g, clipBounds, cellBounds2, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle2);

                    var rightBottomCell = DataGridView[columnIndex + columnSpan - 1, rowIndex + rowSpan - 1] as DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx ?? this;
                    var advancedBorderStyle3 = new DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle
                    {
                        Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                        Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                        Right = advancedBorderStyle.Right,
                        Bottom = advancedBorderStyle.Bottom
                    };
                    rightBottomCell.PaintBorder(g, clipBounds, cellBounds2, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle3);

                }
            }

            // Set the new Clip Bounds to the bounds which are calulcated for the row to span.
            graphics.SetClip(clipBounds);

            //Paint the content.
            ownerCell.NativePaint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds2, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);

            //Paint the borders.
            if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None)
            {
                var leftTopCell = ownerCell;
                var advancedBorderStyle2 = new DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle
                {
                    Left = advancedBorderStyle.Left,
                    Top = advancedBorderStyle.Top,
                    Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                    Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
                };
                leftTopCell.PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds2, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle2);

                var rightBottomCell = DataGridView[columnIndex + columnSpan - 1, rowIndex + rowSpan - 1] as DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx ?? this;
                var advancedBorderStyle3 = new DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle
                {
                    Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                    Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None,
                    Right = advancedBorderStyle.Right,
                    Bottom = advancedBorderStyle.Bottom
                };
                rightBottomCell.PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds2, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle3);

            }

            // Restore old Bounds! Otherwise only the spanned row will be painted
            graphics.SetClip(oldBounds);
        }
```

И ещё здесь потребовалась правка:

```
        protected override System.Drawing.Rectangle BorderWidths(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle)
        {
            if (m_OwnerCell == null && m_ColumnSpan == 1 && m_RowSpan == 1)
            {
                return base.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
            }

            if (m_OwnerCell != null)
            {
                return m_OwnerCell.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
            }

            var leftTop = base.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
            var rightBottomCell = DataGridView[
                ColumnIndex + ColumnSpan - 1,
                RowIndex + RowSpan - 1] as DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx;
            var rightBottom = rightBottomCell != null
                ? NativeBorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle)
                : leftTop;
            return new System.Drawing.Rectangle(leftTop.X, leftTop.Y, rightBottom.Width, rightBottom.Height);
        }
```